# Код ничего не выводит. В чём проблема?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема. Код ничего не выводит, хотя должен выводить: "Строка N, Столбец N".

Основная функции программы выглядит так:

```
def Function_main(m,n):
    for row, arr in enumerate(m):
        for col, value in enumerate(arr):
            if value == n:
                print(f'Строка {row+1}, столбец {col+1}')

Function_main([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]],3)
```

Программа выводит:

```
Строка 1, столбец 3
```

Всё верно.

Но я решил добавить ввод матрицы, при условии, что матрица может хранить в себе элементы любого типа, и числа с клавиатуры, и после этого код перестал выводить ответ:

```
def Function_m():
    x=input('Введите мартицу "Построчно, через запятую: "')
    return x

def Function_n():
    while True:
        try:
            y=int(input('Введите номер элемента: '))
            if y<1:
                raise ValueError
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('Ошибка в вводе')
    return y

def Function_main(m,n):
    for row, arr in enumerate(m):
        for col, value in enumerate(arr):
            if value == n:
                print(f'Строка {row+1}, столбец {col+1}')
                
m= Function_m()

n= Function_n()

Function_main(m,n)
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: `return()`?....

Comment: В вашем случае, если после m = Functionm() написать print(m) будет None. 
Ваши функции Functionm и Functionn ничего не выводят. Исправьте на return x и return y.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
def Function_n():
    y = input('Введите номер элемента: ')
    if y.isdigit() == False or int(y) < 1:
        print('Ошибка в вводе')
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]